# Blender how to create new image without color?

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

In blender , when creating new image , there is this option
[image]
but i don't want color in it , i want a full transparent image because i gonna paint over it later and save it as png.

How do i create new image without color ? the only workaround i can found is to create the transparent image outside blender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activate the *Alpha* option, click on the color field an lower the *Alpha* value down to 0:

[image]

Also, in *Paint* mode you can set your brush to *Blend > Erase Alpha*, which will create an alpha layer.

Comment: thanks it worked ! i thought settings the alpha value will make the image transparent , but no , it turns out it only make the initial color that transparent not after , i still can paint over it !

Comment: and anyway in Paint mode you can set your brush to Blend > Erase Alpha  ;)